# GROUP_CONCAT(MySQL) in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(date + ',' + name + ',' + comment) As `data`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY id
```

This syntax works in MySQL, how can I make this in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no string aggregates in SQL Server, but you can try XML routines for this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    (
        SELECT
            date + ',' + name + ',' + comment AS 'text()'
        FROM
            [table] as xml
        WHERE
            xml.id = [table].id
        FOR
            XML PATH('')
    )
FROM
    [table]
GROUP BY
    id
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT id,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + b.date + ',' + b.name + ',' + b.comment
                  FROM `table` b
                  WHERE b.id = a.id
                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS [Output]
    FROM `table` a
    GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: How will the inner select works if you're trying to use fields, those aren't in GROUP BY clause? I've a feeling, that you'll get an error.